# Resize ios Video iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, video, resize, avfoundation

I've a video (with an audio channel) on the disk. I've the NSURL of this video and I want to resize it.

I've tried many solutions since a week but none worked well.

So I'm looking for an hint of what I've to do ?

Thanks,

Alak

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found an Apple's code sample AVReaderWriterOfflineAudioVideoProcessing where there a classe : "CyanifyOperation". I've modified this class. (and rollback it in swift 1.2)

https://github.com/Alak/ResizeOperation